# Add-Migration showing error EntityFrameworkCore.Design is not installed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, nuget, entity-framework-core

I am following the tutorial for EntityFrameworkCore in here 
https://docs.efproject.net/en/staging/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html
But when i reach the create database part of the tutorial
https://docs.efproject.net/en/staging/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html#create-your-database
and run the command Add-Migration MyFirstMigration  I get the following error:

```
Cannot execute this command because Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design is not installed. Install the version of that package that matches the installed version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and try again.
```

I tried to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design as well as Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design every single version there is on NuGet but still get the same error.

I also tried to run outside of the NuGet PM using the command

- dotnet restore
- dotnet ef migrations add MyFirstMigration

And got the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Entry point not found in assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
```

I tried everything I could think of and looked everywhere on the internet but still came up short of an answer.

Comment: You should probably post your project.json - normally the problem can be identified there.

Comment: See this link, maybe that can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66618882/7890100

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check that your project.json contains these entries

under dependencies:

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
},

"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
```

under tools:

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "imports": [
    "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
},
```

Comment: This one worked for me and I was able to use the Add-Migration with succes on app and web application, the problem is that my Context is in a library and the 1.0.0-preview2-final is not compatible with the NETStandard.Library, god knows why.

I am using a workaround right now and compiling my library as an command app, and it is working so far. Still I hope that microsoft updates their library and documentation soon, this is far away from my desired architecture.

Comment: @Destino Feel free to mark as answer since it fixed your problem.

Answer (score 2):

First, this document using VS2015 Update2 and current latest version for VS2015 is Update 3. So I suggest you upgrade your VS2015 to Update 3, which has fixed a lot of VS bugs.

Then according to the tutorial, I get the same error message when I run the command Add-Migration MyFirstMigration. Then I run command "Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" in Package Manager Console to install the EntityFrameworkCore.Design. After install it, when I run the command Add-Migration MyFirstMigration, it added successful.

Following is my project.json file content. Please check the dependencies and tools version. Make sure they are in correct versions.

```
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "platform"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview3-final",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.0.1"
},

"tools": {
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
},
```

Comment: I voted up because it might help some people experiencing thesse problems.
Your solution doesn't work for me because youre using design 1.0.1 and tools 1.0.0-preview3-final and they don't seem to be compatible.

Comment: preview3 tools was released with efcore 1.1 (which is pre-release currently) - if you are using 1.0.1 you should probably use preview2 tools

Answer (score 0):

I am a .net / c# noob and always wanted to learn web-coding on the side. Never did though - until I understood blazor and how it would make it possible for me to have an environment that I can handle and learn by myself.

This error had me crash hard and spend nights of research (VS 16.5.0 with EF 3.2.0).
Until I finally discovered why I got the error and could not follow the tutorials.

Apparently one dependency is created as `_._` as opposed to the correct reference (see image)

[corrupt dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vtLV.png)

Comment: sorry: it's line 218 in the image. The left is correct

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should try, where possible, to include code in your answer in a minimal form if appropriate. Relying on external links, especially images, can prove problematic if that link disappears, and can mean that search engines won't be able to find all of the content of your answer.